# MS CRM 2011 Custom workflow log

Tags: logging, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to write a message in the details message of a system job?
I only know the way to get the ITracingService and make some traces. But these tracing lines will only be shown if my custom workflow throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know; no, I experimented with this in the past, going so far as to write update calls to the system job field but I was prevented by CRM if I remember correctly.

The second best option is to create a 'log' entity which you write messages to.

Comment: Thanks. How did you get the correct WorkflowId for the update request? I would also try your way, maybe I can do the update request

Comment: It was a while ago now, cant remember exactly, I think an ID in the context object matched the ID of the system job so I worked it out that way.